# Having issues with a table with big numbers

Tags: tables

for my duty i have to make a table with big numbers in it and latex can t run it, i make the code and theb latex keep running indefinitely and writes :" pdflatex warning running with administrator privileges" while running it.
Here is the code :

```
\begin{table}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
  {\bf bla} & {\bf fsf} &  {\bf sffs} &  {\bf sfdfs} \\
  \hline
  2008 & 76767 & 28 775 910 793,00 & 374847,4057 \\
  \hline 2009 & 74409 & 28 043 718 116,00 & 376866,104   \\
    \hline 2010 & 69179 & 26 100 923 568,00 & 376207,8376 \\
      \hline 2011 &66974 & 25 151 179 216,00 & 375536,4651 \\
 \hline   2012 & 62250 & 23 412 377 214,00 & 376102,4452  \\
      \hline 2013 & 58397 & 21 861 625 892,00 & 374362,14 \\
      \hline 2014 & 59854 & 22 394 933 585,00 & 374159,3475 \\
   \hline 2015 & 58654 & 21 921 562 055,00 & 373743,6842  \\
  \hline    2016 & 59919 & 22 469 492 718,00 & 374997,7923 \\
  \hline    2017 & 58894 & 22 263 639 376,00 & 378028,9907 \\

  \hline {\bf Total} & {\bf 645469} &{\bf 242 395 362 533,00} & {\bf 3758472,212} \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
{\bf \caption{bla bla.}}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for the help tou will provide to me .

Comment: Although there are various questionable decisions (such as the use of `\bf` which is an obsolete and deprecated command) here, the table compiles for me. The problem must be somewhere else in the document. Constructing a self-contained MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) may help you track it down.

Comment: The rest of the document compiles without any probleme and i don t understand why this table doesn't , i have another table with the same code but smaller values and it compiles without any problem .

Comment: If Paul is correct that the table given here compiles correctly on its own (which you can verify by making a new empty document and copying/pasting the above table code into it), then whatever problem you're running into is not due to this table, but something else in your document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have any particular insights to offer regarding the "pdflatex warning running with administrator privileges" message. Which operating system is installed on your system, and which TeX distribution do you employ?

I do have some suggestions regarding the table: To improve legibility, I think it would be a good idea to align all numbers on the (implied or explicit) decimal markers. One way to achieve this is to load the `siunitx` package and to employ the `S` column type for columns 2, 3, and 4. Note that when typesetting bold numbers in a table, it's a good idea to use a non-extended bold font, to allow easy alignment of bold-weight and non-bold-weight numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % provide a more open "look"
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for "\renewrobustcmd" macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
% Redefine \bfseries: "regular", not "extended"
\renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|S[table-format=6.0,group-digits=false]|
                   S[table-format=12.2]|
                   S[table-format=7.4,group-digits=false] |}
  \hline
  \textbf{bla} & {\textbf{fsf}} & {\textbf{sffs}} & {\textbf{sfdfs}} \\ \hline
  2008 & 76767 & 28775910793,00 & 374847,4057 \\ \hline 
  2009 & 74409 & 28043718116,00 & 376866,104  \\ \hline 
  2010 & 69179 & 26100923568,00 & 376207,8376 \\ \hline 
  2011 & 66974 & 25151179216,00 & 375536,4651 \\ \hline 
  2012 & 62250 & 23412377214,00 & 376102,4452 \\ \hline 
  2013 & 58397 & 21861625892,00 & 374362,14   \\ \hline 
  2014 & 59854 & 22394933585,00 & 374159,3475 \\ \hline
  2015 & 58654 & 21921562055,00 & 373743,6842 \\ \hline 
  2016 & 59919 & 22469492718,00 & 374997,7923 \\ \hline    
  2017 & 58894 & 22263639376,00 & 378028,9907 \\ \hline 
  \textbf{Total} & \bfseries 645469 & 
  \bfseries 242395362533,00 & \bfseries 3758472,212 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{bla bla.}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i wil try it, it just my others table compile without any problem excepting this one and i don t know why that s why it s frustrating me, thanks agakn